# Get text from paragraphs with php

Tags: php, html, dom

Supposing I have 2 paragraphs

```
<p id="p1" class="code-output">This is a first paragraph</p>
<p id="p2" class="code-output">This is the 2nd paragraph</p>
```

Is there any way to save the inner text of those paragraphs into php variables?